# Remove default variables from Spyder Variable Explore

Tags: python, variables, spyder

Is there a specific code or a setting on Spyder that can remove the default variables from the variables explorer?

I have changed the settings so that all variables are cleared each time I click run but the variable explore shows some default values (e.g values such pi, e, euler_gamma, cast, ScalarType and many more).

I have tried to play around with the settings and search on google but can't find any solution.

See screenshot (all the default variables have been highlighted)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, you need to untick the following box in SpyderIDE preferences:

Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Automatically load Pylab and NumPy modules